# Caliburn.micro View ViewModel name resolution issue

Tags: c#, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am using a namespace called `ComShorCaliburnWPF.ViewModules.Views.ShortMenuWindows.GWDSCT` on my `View.xaml` and `View.cs`, for my `ViewModel.cs` and my IoC container I am using `ComShorCaliburnWPF.ViewModules.Views.ShortMenuWindows.GWDSCT`. When I remove the GWDSCT at the end it works fine, but in its current state it does not. I would like it to work how it is now because it accurately reflects where the files are located. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add more detail, maybe a code sample?

Answer (score 3):

One thing that will help debug these problems is to use the logger:

```
 public class DebugLogger : ILog
    {
        private readonly Type _type;

        public DebugLogger(Type type)
        {
            _type = type;
        }

        public void Info(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            if (format.StartsWith("No bindable"))
                return;
            if (format.StartsWith("Action Convention Not Applied"))
                return;
            Debug.WriteLine("INFO: " + format, args);
        }

        public void Warn(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("WARN: " + format, args);
        }

        public void Error(Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}\n{1}", _type.Name, exception);
        }
    }
```

Then in `AppBootstrapper`, Configure method.

```
LogManager.GetLog = type => new DebugLogger(type);
```

Comment: Not sure why the down vote, the logger will tell you why it can't resolve names.

Comment: You're right the logger would help. but you could've added bit more details like injecting debugger to caliburn micro engine. It was obvious to get down vote because of lack of details in your answer.

Comment: That's what `LogManager.GetLog = type => new DebugLogger(type);`  Unless it's changed, I haven't used it for a while.